# Underscore.js where() function issue with searching json objects

Tags: javascript, json, list, underscore.js

I have a json collection stored as `{"books": [{...}, ... ]}` in a file. `"books"` is a list of json objects where each is a book. For example:

```
{
 "books": [
  {
   "items": [
    {
     "id": "jD8iswEACAAJ",
     "volumeInfo": {
      "industryIdentifiers": [
       {
        "type": "ISBN_10",
        "identifier": "0984782850"
       },
       {
        "type": "ISBN_13",
        "identifier": "9780984782857"
       }
      ],
     },
    }
   ]
  },
 ]
}
```

I have a need to read the json using  `_.where`, specifically search every item in the collection for the `"identifier"` value of `"type": "ISBN_10"`. Then return the full json object aka `{"items": [...]}`.
Suppose `req.params.id` is the `"identifier"` value (i.e. 0984782850).
This piece of code is not working

```
var _ = require('underscore');
...
app.get('/api/books/:id', function(req, res) {
  var book = _.where(booksData.books.items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0], {identifier: req.params.id});
  res.json(book);
});
```

it is returning

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at position 43
```

The file has valid json, I have tried

```
var book = _.where(booksData.books, {items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier: req.params.id});
```

which also does not work

There is always one item in `"items"` and the ISBN_10 identifier is the first item in `"industryIdentifiers"` hence `items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier`

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT: I tried with `industryIdentifiers`, but response is `[ ]`

Comment: Could you use the javascript filter command?  `booksData.books.filter ( book => book.items.filter( item => item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.type === 'ISBN_10').length > 0).length > 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `industryIdentifiers[1]`. You want to search the entire `industryIdentifiers` array, not a single object.

```
var book = _.where(booksData.books[0].items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, {identifier: req.params.id})[0];
```

You also need `books[0]`, since `books` is also an array.

```js
const booksData = {
 "books": [
  {
   "items": [
    {
     "id": "jD8iswEACAAJ",
     "volumeInfo": {
      "industryIdentifiers": [
       {
        "type": "ISBN_10",
        "identifier": "0984782850"
       },
       {
        "type": "ISBN_13",
        "identifier": "9780984782857"
       }
      ],
     },
    }
   ]
  },
 ]
};
var book = _.where(booksData.books[0].items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, {identifier: "0984782850"})[0];
console.log(book);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried this change, but I am getting `[ ]` in the response. I should be getting the json [Object]

Comment: `_.where` returns an array, since there could be more than one element that meets the condition. If you only need the first one, index it.

Comment: I've added `[0]` at the end to return just the first one.

Comment: so I am expecting `{"items": [...]}`. The identifier is distinct and if it exists (does), it should be returning just one

Comment: Did you add `books[0]`?

Comment: `items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier:` is not valid syntax.

Comment: yes, its invalid syntax, and yes I last added `books[0]` such as `var book = _.where(booksData.books[0].items[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, {identifier: parseInt(req.params.id)});` but its `[ ]`

Comment: `books[0]` is implying the first book but `"books"` has multiple `{"items": [...]}` so it should be searching all

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can get it to search through all the nested arrays in one call, you need to loop over the containing arrays.

Comment: I am trying `var book = _.where(booksData.books, {items[0]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'].identifier[0]: parseInt(req.params.id)});`, but it errors at the `[`

Comment: Of course it does, that's not valid syntax for an object literal.

Comment: The key of an object has to be a string.